# Embed CSS into HTML file with Grunt

Tags: html, css, gruntjs

I need to replace tags in HTML file like this:

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="template.css">
```

With the following:

```
<style type="text/css"> { /* content of template.css */ } </style>
```

Using [Grunt](http://gruntjs.com/).

What is the best way of achieving this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert your HTML file to a [Twig](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/documentation) template. Embed your CSS file with `{% include %}` operator. Then use [consolidate.js](https://github.com/visionmedia/consolidate.js/) with [atpl.js](https://github.com/soywiz/atpl.js) through [grunt-consolidate](https://github.com/mikevercoelen/grunt-consolidate) plugin to compile it.

[Twig](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/documentation) is used in [Symfony2](http://symfony.com/) project and based on [Django template language](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/templates/) and is one of the most elegant and powerful ones for server-side compilation.

If you want you can use another compiler with *include* functionality, cause [Consolidate](https://github.com/visionmedia/consolidate.js/), [supports lots of them](https://github.com/visionmedia/consolidate.js/#supported-template-engines).

See the provided links for more details.